How to handle errors thrown in onAuthStateChanged in firebase auth
The app uses the existence of the user in the auth context to determine if they are logged in. This state is set in onAuthStateChanged on login. This works fine as is, however, I want to be able to handle errors in case my API returns one and display it on the login page.
On the login page, after a successful login, the user is navigated to the dashboard page. If the firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword fails, that is caught and displayed to the user. However, if there is an error in the onAuthStateChanged from getApiUser or createApiUser, this does not get caught because the error is thrown outside the login function. So the login succeeds and navigate is called. I have a <ProtectedRoute> component that detects if the user is null, so they are just redirected back to the login page in this case. However, they would not see an error and would be confused why the login did not work.
Things I've considered

I've considered moving the getApiUser and createApiUser logic to the login function itself, that way the errors would be caught in the login page. However, the getApiUser has to live in onAuthstateChanged otherwise if you refresh the page, the user will be reset to null, effectively logging out the user.

I've also tried creating a new context value called error that gets set from any errors thrown in onAuthStateChanged. Then the login page would just use that error context value instead of creating its own. However, this still does not prevent navigate from being called.


// LoginPage.tsx

export function LoginPage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { login } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [pass, setPass] = usestate('');

  const handleLoginClick = () => {
    try {
      await login(email, pass);
      navigate('/dashboard');
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      ..
  )
}

// authContextProvider.tsx

...
const [user, setUser] = useState<ApiUser | null>(null);

const login = async (email, pass) => {
  await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass);
}

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (firebaseUser) => {
    if (!firebaseUser) {
      setUser(null);
    } else {
      try {
        // Fetch user from API.
        const apiUser = await getApiUser(firebaseUser.uid);

        if (apiUser) {
          setUser(apiUser);

        } else if (firebaseUser.emailVerified) {
          // This is a new user. Create them in the API.
          const newUser = await createApiUser(firebaseUser.uid);
          setUser(newUser);

        } else {
          // This user has not yet been verified.
          setUser(null);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setUser(null);
        await logout();
      }
    }
  });

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);


onAuthStateChanged itself doesn't generate errors.  It just reflects the current state of the user in your provided callback.  You are free to check your own code for errors inside the callback and determine what to do with it. You'll have to figure out your own react state to set and respond to if that happens (it sounds like you'll need more than just setUser).  We can't tell you how you should handle errors in your app - that's entirely up to your product's requirements.
